# Preventing double votes with customer number SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am making a voting system whereby users can upvote or downvote on other users entries into a sql database. Each user receives a unique 8 digit customer number which they can use to vote (as this customer number is the primary key in the table).

I am trying to prevent a user from voting twice on the same entry by entering their customer number into a voted column. However, I don't know how to keep adding customer numbers to the same voted column and prevent a double vote by finding if the customer number is contained in the voted column (in the code below you will see that I have tried `CHARINDEX` to find if the 8 digit customer number already exists in the voted column but this doesn't work).

My Code:

```
this.companyName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
string upvoteUpdateQuery = "UPDATE dbo.clientDataTable SET upvote = upvote + 1 WHERE compName = @compName";

SqlCommand Upvote = new SqlCommand(upvoteUpdateQuery, voteDb);
Upvote.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compName", this.companyName);

string insertQuery = "IF CHARINDEX ('voted','@voted') != 8 UPDATE dbo.clientDataTable SET voted += @voted)"
+ "WHERE compName = @compName ELSE PRINT 'Error, duplicate vote'"; //prevents double voting by seeing if all 8 digits by customer number match, if they don't it works else print
//checks if voted customers id exists using charindex, if it doesn't then vote will happen

SqlCommand insertVoterDetailsUpvote = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, voteDb); //inserts voter information into specific entries table
insertVoterDetailsUpvote.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voted", custVoteTextBox.Text);
insertVoterDetailsUpvote.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compName", this.companyName);

voteDb.Open();
Upvote.ExecuteNonQuery();
voteDb.Close();
```

Comment: you can try the EXISTS keyword. If Exists(Select * from Table where articleID = x and VotedUser = Y) Begin....End

Comment: You can create a unique index on the table on voted and compName and catch the exception if a vote occurs 2x. Create a transaction around the update and insert, if both occur without a problem commit it and if an exception occurs roll it back and return an error message to the user.

Comment: Can't you use a [UNIQUE constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) to achieve this effect?

Comment: Show us your table definitions.  That's where the problems are.

Comment: Please provide the DDL (your sql schema).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't be packing an arbitrary number of IDs into a single character column.

A better schema would be a votes table, e.g. `dbo.Votes` with columns for referencing the entry and voting user, e.g. `EntryId`, `VoterUserId`, and a column for the vote, e.g. `Vote`. Include an unique constraint on the entry and voting user to prevent duplicates and use `... EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM dbo.Votes WHERE EntryId = @EntryId AND VoterUserId = @VoterUserId )` to check whether a user has already voted on an entry.